# Read matrix from GUI object

Tags: matlab, user-interface, vector, matrix, matlab-guide

I'm writing a program that performs Gauss elimination, and I want to create a GUI for this. For example, if the user wants to input a 2×2 matrix, I want 4 text boxes to appear in the GUI. My problem is that I don't know how to read the values from these objects. My code is below:

```
n=3;
b=50;   
a=200;
for i=1:n    
    for j=1:n
        A(i,j) = uicontrol('style','edit','units','pixels',...
                 'position',[b a 50 50],'fontsize',20,'string','');
       b = b+60;
    end
    b = 50;
    a = a-60;
end

uiwait

for i=1:n
    for j=1:n
        B(i,j) = str2double(get(A(i,j),'String'));
    end
end
```

How to get the input data from `A` to `B`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution #1: Using a trigger button

One solution is to have a trigger in the UI that reads the data from the textboxes. For example, you can add a button that the user must press after entering the input matrix:

```
B = nan(n);
btn = uicontrol('style','pushbutton','units','pixels',...
'position',[b a 170 50],'fontsize',20,'string','Read data', ...
    'Callback', 'for k = 1:n^2, B(k) = str2double(get(A(k),''string'')); end');
```

When the user presses the button, the inline callback function is invoked and matrix `B` is populated. Missing elements will be represented as `NaN` values, so you can verify that all values have been entered with the expression:

```
all(~isnan(B))
```

#### Solution #2: Responding to keystrokes

Another solution is to update matrix `B` as the user is typing in data. To do this, add a callback function to the textboxes themselves like so:

```
A(i,j) = uicontrol('style','edit','units','pixels',...
    'position',[b a 50 50],'fontsize',20,'string','', ...
    'Callback', 'B(A == gco) = str2double(get(gco, ''string''));');
```

The callback uses [`gco`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/gco.html) to find the position in matrix `B` that matches to the textbox that the user is currently typing into, and updates the corresponding element. Remember to initialize `B = nan(n)` before the double for loop!

Comment: I have a question...the #2 solution is working...but if I take the code in a function...(function read()....end)....B = NaN, without function..only the code...work,why?...I wait for a response..thanks for helping

Comment: @alinush2693 Sorry, I don't understand what your asking.

Comment: take a look please...I updated the code....I don't understand why does not work if I use with function...because I want to get the 'B' in another function

Comment: sorry...in the second code The B is full with NaN..not with my numbers...and I don't understand why....because the difference between the first and the second is that I put the code from .m file in a function and does not work

Comment: What I want is to return the B matrix to another function...that's all

Comment: If you're updating `B` in a callback function which is in a separate m-file, you're using a local variable `B` which is different from the variable `B` in the main workspace. A possible (but bad) solution to circumvent this issue is to make `B` a [global variable](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/global.html).